# Static keyword in Swift 3 protocol

Tags: swift, static, swift3, swift-protocols

I noticed that some functions in `Swift` `protocols` have the `static` keyword. However, when you implement the function, you must remove the `static` keyword to make the compiler happy.

```
public static func <(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
```

What does `static` mean in the context and what is its purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From the Xcode 8 beta 4 release notes**:

> Operators can be defined within types or extensions thereof. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> struct Foo: Equatable {
>     let value: Int
>     static func ==(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
>         return lhs.value == rhs.value
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Such operators must be declared as `static` (or, within a class,
>   `class final`), and have the same signature as their global
>   counterparts. As part of this change, operator requirements declared
>   in protocols must also be explicitly declared `static`:
>
> ```
> protocol Equatable {
>     static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

**Static properties and methods**

Swift lets you create properties and methods that belong to a type, rather than to instances of a type. This is helpful for organizing your data meaningfully by storing shared data.

Swift calls these shared properties "static properties", and you create one just by using the static keyword. Once that's done, you access the property by using the full name of the type. Here's a simple example:

```
struct TaylorFan {

    static var favoriteSong = "Shake it Off"
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

let fan = TaylorFan(name: "James", age: 25)

print(TaylorFan.favoriteSong)
```

So, a Taylor Swift fan has a name and age that belongs to them, but they all have the same favorite song.

Because static methods belong to the class rather than to instances of a class, you can't use it to access any non-static properties from the class.